# CheckListBox Set focus to specific index

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I am populating a TChecListBox with a couple hundred items.
I want to have a TEdit box where i can type a string, hit a button next to it and have to TCheckListBox scroll to the first item with a matching substring.

**Is there anything like** `TCheckListBox->Items->ViewIndex[i]` or `TCheckListBox->Scrollto[i]`**?**

Comment: @syam: post it as an answer so you can get credit for it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wasn't sure if the answer was right (haven't used Borland for years, and I was in a hurry so I couldn't verify it) which is why I wrote a comment first. Now that OP has confirmed it, here's the answer. :P

Answer (score 1):

The `TCheckListBox` property you're looking for is `ItemIndex`.